# How to post xml with roUrlTransfer in a Roku App?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

My app needs the "rendezvous" registration, so I need to post XML data to our server. I know roUrlTransfer is used for Http/Https request in Roku App. I also saw some simple examples, but I haven't figured out how to send XML data to a server?
Appreciate it for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the method `PostFromString` or [AsyncPostFromString](https://developer.roku.com/en-ot/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifurltransfer.md#asyncpostfromstringrequest-as-string-as-boolean)? You should convert the XML to a string (`Escape`) and then post it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use "roXMLElement" to create XML object. Once XML Object is created we can use

XMLString = xmlObject.GenXML(true) to convert xml into string

Once the string is created we can use AsyncPostFromString to post the XML content. Also make sure in request header you add content-type as "application/xml"